# How do I check RAM manufacturer?

Tags: command-line, ram, system-info

I just brought a new `8GB 3200 MHz` RAM of `SAMSUNG`.
But I want to confirm that it is real Samsung RAM or fake.

Please tell me how do i check it from terminal.

Note :
My laptop has two RAM slot of 8GB each.
I am using Kubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 8):

This will list anything you need to know about your hardware:

```
sudo dmidecode
```

Example:

```
...
Handle 0x0008, DMI type 17, 92 bytes
Memory Device
    ...
    Total Width: 16 bits
    Data Width: 16 bits
    Size: 2 GB
    Form Factor: Row Of Chips
    Set: None
    Locator: Controller1-ChannelD
    Bank Locator: BANK 3
    Type: LPDDR4
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 4267 MT/s
    Manufacturer: Samsung
    ...
```

ONLY memory:

```
sudo dmidecode -t memory
```

Comment: And if you only want to see memory `sudo dmidecode -t memory`

Comment: I just checked by above mentioned code and it is showing `Manufacturer: Micron`

Comment: But I brought Samsung. Is it FAKE or REAL ?

Comment: This claims Micron is less bandwith https://www.eetasia.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2022/02/DDR5_Table1.jpg so if it is a concern you might want to trade it in for a samsung.